# Strange behavior E-matching with interpreted functions in Z3

Tags: z3

Given the following Z3 preamble (in SMT2 format):

```
(set-option :smt.auto-config false)
(set-option :smt.mbqi false)

(declare-fun exp (Real) Real)
(declare-fun foo (Real) Real)
(declare-fun bar (Real Real) Real)

(assert (forall ((x Real) (y Real)) (= (* (exp x) (exp y)) (exp (+ x y)))))

(declare-const x Real)
(declare-const y Real)
(declare-const z Real)
```

`unsat` can be deduced from both of the following goals (individually) within a few milliseconds:

```
(assert (not (= (+ z (* (exp x) (exp y))) (+ z (exp (+ x y))))))                                                                                                                                         
(assert (not (= (foo (bar z (* (exp x) (exp y)))) (foo (bar z (exp (+ x y)))))))
```

However, Z3 times out when given the goal:

```
(assert (not (= (foo (+ z (* (exp x) (exp y)))) (foo (+ z (exp (+ x y)))))))
```

which can be seen as either wrapping both sides of the first goal in `foo`, or as replacing `bar` with `+` in the second goal.

This goal can be proved if we annotate the lemma with either of the following two patterns:

```
(assert (forall ((x Real) (y Real)) (! (= (* (exp x) (exp y)) (exp (+ x y))) :pattern (* (exp x) (exp y)))))                              
(assert (forall ((x Real) (y Real)) (! (= (* (exp x) (exp y)) (exp (+ x y))) :pattern (exp (+ x y)))))
```

Thus I presume that the multi-pattern `((exp x) (exp y))` is being generated by default, though I am not sure why this pattern would behave any differently if both sides are wrapped in `foo`, or if `+ z` is replaced with `bar z`.

What is going on here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's going on in your situation, but you might try giving Z3 additional information about the `exp` function.  One option is:

```
(assert (exists ((EULER_E Real)) (forall ((x Real)) (= (exp x) (^ EULER_E x)))))
```

I'm pretty sure that's written correctly, but I haven't used nested quantifiers much in SMT-LIB so please be careful. Another option that's a bit more explicit would be:

```
(declare-const EULER_E Real)
(assert (> EULER_E 2.718281828459045))
(assert (< EULER_E 2.718281828459046))
(assert (forall ((x Real)) (= (exp x) (^ EULER_E x))))
```

Adding either of the above makes Z3 come back `unsat` for your example.